# tm.plugin.sentiment package is not available for R version 3.4.3

Tags: r, tm

received following error message:

```
install.packages(c('tm', 'tm.plugin.sentiment'))
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.sentiment)

# warning: package ‘tm.plugin.sentiment’ is not available(for R version 3.4.3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 1):

tm.plugin.sentiment package not available in cran repository.
You can download this package from Github.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment")
```

You can find more information about this package from https://github.com/mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment